# Why is this call to member function ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider this class:

```
class Base{
public:
    void func(double a) = delete;
    void func(int a) const {}
};

int main(){
    Base base;

    base.func(1);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled using clang++, it produces the following error:

```
clang++ --std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp:22:7: error: call to member function 'func' is ambiguous
    base.func(1);
```

With g++, a warning is produced:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:22:13: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: base.func(1);
```

Why is this code ambiguous ?

Comment: Integers can easily be converted to floating point types. While `func(int)` is the best match, `func(double)` is still a viable alternative, making the call ambiguous.

Comment: You seem to be running into some tricky logic involving const and non-const member functions. FWIW, changing `func(double)` to a `const` member function removes the problem.

Comment: @R Sahu: it didnn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Non-static member functions, like the two:

```
void func(double);    // #1
void func(int) const; // #2
```

accept also an [implicit object parameter](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#4) which is considered in overload resolution ([[over.match]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#1)) as any other argument:

> Overload resolution is a mechanism for selecting the best function to call given a list of expressions that are to be the arguments of the call and a set of candidate functions that can be called based on the context of the call. The selection criteria for the best function are the number of arguments, how well the arguments match the parameter-type-list of the candidate function, **how well (for non-static member functions) the object matches the implicit object parameter**, and certain other properties of the candidate function.

After incorporating the implicit object parameter into the member functions signatures, the compiler sees two overloads:

```
void func(Base&, double);    // #1
void func(const Base&, int); // #2
```

and tries to select the best viable function based on the call:

```
Base base;
base.func(1);
```

The conversion from `base` (which is a non-const lvalue of type `Base`) to `Base&` has an *Exact Match* rank (direct reference binding yields an [*Identity conversion*](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1)) -- see [Table 13](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#tab:over.conversions). The conversion from `base` to `const Base&` is also of an *Exact Match* rank, however, [[over.ics.rank]/p3.2.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6) declares `#1` to have a better conversion sequence:

> — S1 and S2 are reference bindings ([[dcl.init.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref)), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> int f(const int &);
> int f(int &);
> int g(const int &);
> int g(int);
>
> int i;
> int j = f(i);    // calls f(int &)
> int k = g(i);    // ambiguous
> ```

Now for the second parameter, a conversion from an integral prvalue `1` to `double` is a *Floating-integral conversion* ([[conv.fpint]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#2)) which is given a *Conversion* rank. On the other hand, `1` to `int` is an *Identity conversion* which is of an *Exact Match* rank. For this argument, `#2` is considered to have a better conversion sequence ([[over.ics.rank]/p3.2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.2)):

> — the rank of S1 is better than the rank of S2, or S1 and S2 have the same rank and are distinguishable by the rules in the paragraph below, or, if not that, [...]

Overload resolution to succeed requires that there exists at most one parameter for which conversion sequences differ ([[over.match.best]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1)):

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICS<sub>i</sub>(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS<sub>i</sub>(F2), and then
>
> — for some argument j, ICS<sub>j</sub>(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICS<sub>j</sub>(F2), or, if not that, [...]

Here, ICS<sub>0</sub>(#1) is better than ICS<sub>0</sub>(#2), but in turn, ICS<sub>1</sub>(#2) is better than ICS<sub>1</sub>(#1), so the compiler can't choose between the two overloads and detects ambiguity.

Comment: I just wanted to post a similar answer. One difference: why do you write `Base*`? 13.3.1.4 says that the implicit object parameter is "lvalue reference to cv X", so `Base &`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a tiny bit of nitpicking: `const base&` also binds directly to the argument of type `base`, so the corresponding implicit conversion sequence is also an identity conversion; there's no qualification conversion. It's just that the conditions in the bullet you quoted are satisfied, which makes the other conversion (to `base&`) better.

Comment: @bogdan I was unsure about this part, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is overloaded, the overload resolution takes place first. The program is ill-formed if the deleted function is the best match and is selected.

Therefore, your program would produce the same error as the following, because there is an implicit conversion from int to double and the compiler does not know what function you intend to call:

```
class Base{
public:
    void func(double a) {}
    void func(int a) const {}
};
```

Comment: your explanation is lacking: yes there is an implicit conversion `int`->`double`, but `int` is a perfect match for the argument. The final key lies with the `const`

Answer (score -1):

It because of the `const` modifier in `func(int)`. The `base` instance is not const. C++ compilers seem to find the `non-const` method first if the instance is not const. And then, compilers found that method has been deleted. So the compiler gives a warning.

Try to remove the `const` modifier, or move the `const` modifier to `func(double)` will get rid of the warning.

It seems that this warning is not about implicit conversion. Even you invoke `func` by `func((int)(1))` is not good either.

Comment: you are wrong. It doesn't find the 1st method first. The two are ambiguous.