# Conflicting overloads with using-declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, using-declaration

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
  void test() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};
struct B : A {
  void test() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};
struct C : B {
  using A::test;
  using B::test;
};
int main() {
  C().test();  // Is this ambiguous?
  return 0;
}
```

In this example, g++ 8.1.0 compiles successfully and calls `test()` from `B`.

clang++ 3.8.0 reports: `error: call to member function 'test' is ambiguous`.

Which is correct? If it is g++, what is the rule that picks `B::test` over `A::test`?

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573771/why-is-this-call-to-member-function-ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Clang is correct.
According to [[namespace.udecl]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/namespace.udecl#13):

> Since a *using-declaration* is a declaration, the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same declarative region ([basic.scope]) also apply to *using-declarations*.

Since you can't declare two identical member functions, the same applies to `using` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

GCC lets it compile and `test()` call becomes the first declaration. In the example given, it'll call the `A::test()`. But ISO C++ defines it as ambiguous. Visual Studio and clang won't let you compile it. Additionally, this the VS error message: `'B::test': ambiguous call to overloaded function`. In my opinion, GCC is wrong by letting it compile.